# jQuery slide row up and add another at the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a HTML table consisting of ten rows. From these ten rows I need to show only 5 at a time. After a given time period the top row should disappear and there should be a new row added at the bottom (row no. 6). 
At the begging the table should consist of rows 1-2-3-4-5 and after the transition 2-3-4-5-6. The process should repeat itself after the same amount of time resulting in 3-4-5-6-7 table. After all rows have been cycled through, the process should begin from 1-2-3-4-5 table. 
All of this should happen with a nice transition effect.

Can you help me?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Great news! We CAN help you --- as long as you've tried first. Post what you've got so we know where to work from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the setinterval function in jquery to repeat the operation.

Use css initially to show the first 5 table rows

```
table tr {
  display: none;
}
table tr:nth-child(-n+5){
    display:block;
}
```

```js
$(function(){
    var i = 0;
    setInterval(function () {
       var sel = 'table tbody tr:nth-child(' + i + ')';
       $(sel).css("display", "none");
       var last = i + 5;
       if(last > 10) last = last % 10;
       var sel1 = 'table tbody tr:nth-child(' + last+ ')';
       $(sel1).css("display", "block");
       i++;
       if(i == 11)
         i = 1;
    },2000);
})
```

```css
table tr {
  display: none;
}
table tr:nth-child(-n+5){
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="table-body">
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td>8</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td>9</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td>10</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: That's great, but when all the rows disappear, how do I make it start over?

Comment: @martin49 Your requirement did'nt mention it thats why I did not take it in consideration. I will try and edit the snippet for it.

Comment: Thank you! I'm very grateful for your help :)

Comment: @martin49 Kindly accept the answer if it helped you